# tag property immediate doesn't work

Tags: visualforce, tag

inside a Vf page i have one required field and two action buttons. When a user clicks on a specific button, the action has to start despite the required fields and the validation rules. I put the property immediate=true on the button but it doesn't work. 
Here my code:

```
<apex:PageBlock id="contratto">
    <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
        <apex:commandButton action="{!createContr}" value="Scegli i Prodotti" reRender="panprodotti" />
        <apex:commandButton action="{!goback}" value="Torna a Scheda Cliente" immediate="true" />
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Specifiche Contratto" collapsible="false">
        <apex:input required="true" label="Data inizio contratto" value="{!cData}" type="date" id="datainiziocontr" />
        <apex:input label="Durata contratto(mesi)" value="{!cDurata}" type="number" id="durcontr" />
        <apex:input label="Condizioni speciali" value="{!cCondizioni}" type="text" id="condizioni" />
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:PageBlock>
```

Now when a user clicks the button "Torna a Scheda Cliente" , a message pops out because "Data inizio contratto" is required, but I want to skip it, how can i do that?

controller:

```
public with sharing class NuovoContrattoExstension {
    public String SelectedRowId {get; set;}
    public String retURL {get;set;}
    public Date cData {get;set;}
    public String cCondizioni {get;set;}
    public Integer cDurata {get;set;}
    public Prodotto_contratto__c prodotto{get;set;}
    public Integer gionol {get;set;}
    public Integer quant {get;set;}
    public Integer sconto {get;set;}
    public List<Prodotto_contratto__c> shoppingCart {get;set;}
    public Id accid {get;set;}
    public Contract nuovocontratto;

    public NuovoContrattoExstension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    try{
        prodotto=new  Prodotto_contratto__c();
        shoppingCart= new List<Prodotto_contratto__c>();
        System.debug(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('X'));
        accid=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('X');
        System.debug(accid);
        }catch(Exception e){
         ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        }


    }

    public Pagereference deleteRow(){
     try{
        System.debug('fatto');
        System.debug(ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('rowid'));
        System.debug(SelectedRowId);
        for (Integer i = 0; i < shoppingCart.size(); i++) {
            Prodotto_contratto__c a = shoppingCart[i];
                if (a.Id == SelectedRowId) {
                    delete a;
                    shoppingCart.remove(i);
                    break;
                    }
        }
        }catch(Exception e){
         ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void createContr(){
     try{
        nuovocontratto= new Contract();
        nuovocontratto.AccountId=accid;
        nuovocontratto.StartDate=cData;
        nuovocontratto.ContractTerm=cDurata;
        nuovocontratto.SpecialTerms=cCondizioni;
        insert nuovocontratto;
        System.debug('contratto'+nuovocontratto.id);
        }catch(Exception e){
         ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        }
    }

    public void removeFromShoppingCart(){
    }

    public void addFromShoppingCart(){
    try{
        System.debug('Creazione Prodotto');
    prodotto.Name='prodotto in contratto';
    prodotto.Contratto__c=nuovocontratto.id;
    prodotto.Contatto__c=accid;
        System.debug(prodotto.Name);
        System.debug(prodotto.Contratto__c);
        System.debug(prodotto.Scelta__c);
        System.debug(prodotto.Quantit_prodotto__c);
        System.debug(prodotto.Contatto__c);
        System.debug(prodotto.Sconto__c);
        System.debug(prodotto.Giorni_durata_noleggio__c);
    insert prodotto;
    System.debug('prodotto '+prodotto.id);
    shoppingCart.add(prodotto);
    prodotto=new  Prodotto_contratto__c();
    }catch(Exception e){
         ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        }
    }

    public Pagereference saveContract(){ 
     Pagereference p= new ApexPages.StandardController(nuovocontratto).view();
     p.setRedirect(true);
      return p;
    }

    public Pagereference goback(){ 
    Account a=[select id from Account where id=:accid];
     Pagereference p= new ApexPages.StandardController(a).view();
     p.setRedirect(true);
      return p;
    }

    public void deleteContract(){
     try{
        System.debug(shoppingCart);
        System.debug(nuovocontratto);
        for(Prodotto_contratto__c c:shoppingCart){
            delete c;}
        delete nuovocontratto;
        nuovocontratto=new Contract();
        shoppingCart= new List<Prodotto_contratto__c>();
        System.debug(nuovocontratto);
        system.debug(shoppingCart);
        }catch(Exception e){
         ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: if required="true" removed, does validation disappear? You can have apex validation. What do you with cData in apex? just save ?

Comment: yes if I remove required attribute , the validation disappear, I post the controller

Comment: whatever I use cData to create a Contract record

Comment: I think its about apex:input, it seems like is not passing with immediate. Do you require input? it should work with apex:inputText

Comment: But I need a Date type, how can i use an inputText?

Comment: <apex:inputField required="true" label="Data inizio" value="{!nuovocontratto.cData__c}" />

Comment: I think this is the answer you are looking for [link](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/31945/30686)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why you have this validation, you are using apex:input tag.
This tag requires html5:

```
<apex:page controller="myController" docType="html-5.0">
```

Now validation is processed by HMTL5, not VisualForce. Thats why immediate option doesn't work.

According to [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/31945/30686) you can disable html validation:

```
<apex:form html-novalidate="true">
```

Or you can use apex:inputField instead:

```
<apex:inputField required="true" label="Data inizio" value="{!nuovocontratto.StartDate}" />
```

Comment: Nice tidbits! I didn't know that feature could be disabled. Sweet.